# Unable to see excel gridlines after export

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and am not understanding how to get gridlines in my excel sheet which after exporting it.

I use this for the export

```
    var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr>";
        var textRange; var j=0;
        tab = document.getElementById('getVehicleStatusTbl'); 
        for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) {
            tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
        }
        tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
        return (sa);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.